# What is actually being doubled when someone has to "double back"?

Tags: meaning, etymology, idioms

I have frequently heard this phrase and used it myself when I've gone in a wrong direction either physically or at work metaphorically. However, I wonder why the phrase is *double back*, since once you realize the mistake that you have made, you only go back the way you came once, not twice or *double* the distance.

Comment: IF you were to look at the tracks your feet are making you'd find that there would now be a double set of them.

Comment: double also means *fold*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is figurative.

If you take a rope, and fold it in half so the loose ends are together and your load/friend is hanging from the other, you have doubled the rope.

Walking out to some point and then walking back along the same route is like walking along a doubled rope, and it draws a contrast with a round trip which may have different routes for the outward leg and the return.

Answer (score 5):

*Doubled* can mean bent back upon itself. When it is used in this sense, it is often paired with *up*, *down*, *back*, and *backward*. Hence when your path turns back upon itself you can say that you *double back*. For examples, see this excerpt from *A New English Dictionary on Historical Principles*:

> **8**. To bend (a piece of cloth, paper, etc.) over, so as to bring the two parts into contact parallel; to fold; to bend (the body, etc.) so as to bring distant parts into proximity; to close, clench (the hand or fist). Often with *up*.
>   <sub><sup>(In quot. 1589, to close <sub><sup>(</sup></sub>the ears<sub><sup>)</sup></sub>.)</sup></sub>
>   <sub><sup>*c* **1430** *Two Cookery Bks.* 39 Take a pese of fayre Canneuas, and doble it. **1589** P<sub><sup>UTTENHAM</sup></sub> *Eng. Poesie* III. xxiii. (Arb.) 282 To solace your eares with pretie conceits after a sort of long scholasticall preceptes which may happen haue doubled them. **1665** H<sub><sup>OOKE</sup></sub> *Microgr.* 9 They double all the Stuff .. that is, they crease it just through the middle .. placing the two edges, or selvages just upon one another. **1694** D<sub><sup>RYDEN</sup></sub> *Love Triumph.* III. i, The page is doubled down. **1778** M<sub><sup>AD</sup></sub>. D’A<sub><sup>RBLAY</sup></sub> *Diary* 3 Aug., He doubled his fist at me. **1874** B<sub><sup>LACKIE</sup></sub> *Self-Cult.* 42 Bending his back, and doubling his chest. **1885** B<sub><sup>IBLE</sup></sub> (R. V.) *Exod.* xxvi. 9 Thou .. shalt double over the sixth curtain in the forefront of the tent. **1893** A. H. S. L<sub><sup>ANDOR</sup></sub> *Hairy Ainu* 54 Crouched as she was, doubled up, with her head on her knees.</sup></sub>
>   **b**. *To double up* (a person): to make to bend or stoop, as by a blow; hence *fig*. to finish up, cause to ‘collapse’. (*slang* or *colloq*.)
>   <sub><sup>**1814** *Sporting Mag.* XLIV. 278 Planting a blow on the side of Perrot, which doubled him up. **1883** J. P<sub><sup>ARKER</sup></sub> *Tyne Ch.* 108 Never saw a man so doubled up [in argument]. **1891** E. W. G<sub><sup>OSSE</sup></sub> *Gossip in Library* xxi. 275 This master of science [pugilism], who doubled up an opponent as if he were plucking a flower.</sup></sub>
>   **c**. *intr*. (for *refl*.) To become folded together or bent over; to fold, bend.
>   <sub><sup>? **1650** *Don Bellianis* 164 With such terrible incounters that the knight .. doubled backward upon his horse. **1875** D<sub><sup>ARWIN</sup></sub> *Insectiv. Plants* vii. 163 After 10 hrs. 15 m. .. the blade quite doubled up. *Mod.* His knees doubled up under him. The leaf has been folded, and tends to double over.</sup></sub>
>   **d**. *Billiards*. (*a*.) *intr*. Of a ball. To rebound. (*b*.) *trans*. To cause (a ball) to rebound: cf. D<sub><sup>OUBLET</sup></sub> 7.
>   <sub><sup>**1885** *Billiards simplified* (1889) 50 If you .. hit the red nearly full, so that it doubles down the table [etc.] *Mod*. You can double the ball into the middle pocket.</sup></sub>
>   **9**. *Naut*. (*trans*.) To sail or pass round or to the other side of (a cape or point), so that the ship’s course is, as it were, doubled or bent upon itself.
>   <sub><sup>**1548** H<sub><sup>ALL</sup></sub> *Chron*., *Hen*. *VIII*. II b, If you wil bring your shippe into the bay of Hardines, you must double y<sup>e</sup> poynt of Gentilnes.  **1585** T. W<sub><sup>ASHINGTON</sup></sub> tr. *Nicholay’s* *Voy*. I. X. 12 B, Having doubled the cape, we passed along. **1665** *Phil*. *Trans*. I. 42 To go into the East Indies without doubling the Cape of Good Hope. **1867** F<sub><sup>REEMAN</sup></sub> *Norm*. *Conq*. (1876) I. v. 295 The invaders doubled the Land’s End and ravaged Cornwall.</sup></sub>
>   **b**. *intr*. To get round. *To double upon* (in naval warfare): to get round to the other side of (an enemy’s fleet), so as to inclose it between two fires.
>   <sub><sup>**1769** F<sub><sup>ALCONER</sup></sub> *Dict*. *Marine* (1789) A a ij b, The lee-line .. cannot so easily double upon the van .. of the enemy. **1856** Emerson *Eng*. *Traits* v. 91 Nelson’s feat of ‘doubling’, or stationing his ships one on the outer bow and another on the outer quarter of each of the enemy’s. **1867** S<sub><sup>MYTH</sup></sub> *Sailor’s Word-bk*., *Doubling upon* .. a hostile fleet .. as Nelson did at the Nile. **1875** F. H<sub><sup>ALL</sup></sub> in *Lippincott’s Mag*. XVI. 751/2 I doubled nimbly round a couple of corners, and paused again</sup></sub>
>   **10**. *intr*. To turn sharply and suddenly in running, as a hunted hare; to turn back on one’s course; to pursue a winding or tortuous course.
>   <sub><sup>**1596** D<sub><sup>RAYTON</sup></sub> *Legends* ii. 382 To the Covert doth himselfe betake Doubling, and creepes from Brake againe to Brake. **1690** D<sub><sup>RYDEN</sup></sub> *Amphitryon* IV. Wks. 1884 VIII. 75 See how he doubles, like a hunted hare. **1724** D<sub><sup>E</sup></sub> F<sub><sup>OE</sup></sub> *Mem. Cavalier* (1840) 95 He found the river fetching a long reach, double short upon itself. **1828** D’I<sub><sup>SRAELI</sup></sub> *Chas. I*, I. iv. 87 The nogociation doubled through all the bland windings of concession and conciliation. **1864** D. G. M<sub><sup>ITCHELL</sup></sub> *Sev. Stor.* 306 They suddenly turned to double upon their walk again.</sup></sub>
>   **11**. *fig*. (*intr*.) To make evasive turns or shifts; to use duplicity, act deceitfully. ? *Obs*.
>   <sub><sup>**1530** P<sub><sup>ALSGR</sup></sub>. 525 2, I double, I varye in tellying of my tale. . . Nay, and you double ones, I have done with you. **1578** H<sub><sup>UNNIS</sup></sub> *Hyveful Hunney* Gen. xii. 25 Why has thou dealt thus craftely And doubled so with mee>? **1624** *Trag. Nero* III. iii. in Bullen *O. Pl.* I. 54 Why with false Auguries have we bin deceiv’d? What, can Celestiall Godheads double too? **1649** *Bounds Publ. Obed.* (1650) 35 Who have been .. attent not to double with their God. **1820** S<sub><sup>COTT</sup></sub> *Ivanhoe* xxxv, If thy tongue doubles with me, I will have it torn from thy misbelieving jaws.</sup></sub>

Answer (score 2):

To double back, is to go back out of your way in the opposite direction you are heading.  The distance between the point where you are at the moment you decide to turn back and go to a previous point where you were is arbitrary.  But going back to that previous point and then returning to where you are at the moment you choose to double back is twice the arbitrary distance.  So in order to double back and then continue on your original path, represents covering the distance twice.  It can be a literal or figurative or metephorical application. For example:

You left your house for the Airport that is 30 miles away.  After you traveled 10 miles from your house, you realize you left your passport, that you need to take with you on your flight to travel.  So you turn around and double back 20 miles to your house to get your passport.  10 miles back to your house and 10 miles back to the point you were at when you realized you had to double back.  When you miss your flight and you have to re book the next flight, you might tell someone who needs to know that the reason you missed your flight is because you had to go out of your way to double back home to get your passport when you were half way to the Airport.   So in simple terms the meaning of double back is actually to go out of your way for something or some reason.

Another example that is metaphorical:
“Mark is a good guy, he will always double back for a friend.”
This a way of saying that Mark is a good friend, he will always go out of his way to help a friend in need.

Double back:  to go out of your way from your path in order to  fulfill an objective before returning to your path.

Answer (score 1):

You double the distance because you made a mistake *to go that way at all*.  Had you avoided your mistake, you would have saved yourself "2x" the travel (out, and back).

Comment: There doesn't need to be a mistake. You could double back because the weather turned bad, you left your phone, or you just got bored.

Comment: @RoaringFish  NewAlexandria is referring to the situation described by OP.

Comment: The real issue to me is the timing of the use of the idiom. When I feel the need to use it, I'm only going to be traveling 1X distance back from that point onward. Yes, I did travel 2x from the time I set out, but I traveled only 1x from the time I used the idiom.

Comment: @Danish that's the fun of this expression!

Answer (score 1):

I have always seen the phrase used as a tactic to throw off pursuit. As in looping wide around in a circle on a trail until you have come across your original tracks. In so doing you are now behind the party who is following you. Which now gives you the advantage to sneak up on them while they think they are sneaking up on you.

There is another as well.

When being pursued you go one direction and then do the same as before, loop around wide back to the original trail and then go a different direction once you meet the beginning of the first loop. In so doing you make two trails for the pursuing party to decide over following once they reach the split. The advantage in this is to

a) Throw the party off entirely, if they are to chose to follow the wrong path. making them loop back around, eventually meeting up with the original trail, putting distance between you.

b) Having the party split in half, one half following the false trail the other half following the correct trail. In so doing their force is only half as strong.

Comment: Hi, J.R.S., and welcome to ELU. I've edited your post to conform with a site preference (no need to second-guess yourself, this is a helpful answer. +1) Since you're here, please have a look at the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour)
and visit the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for guidance on how to use this site. Again, welcome!