# What does "My tongue doubles back" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases, meaning-in-context

I was reading a novel when I came across this phrase.

> "My tongue doubles back in my throat as the senses comes back to mind and I choke on the words, "I love you too."

What does the "my tongue doubles back" mean? Thanks in advance for the answer.

Comment: Literally or figuratively the tip of your tongue goes back into your throat and you choke on it.

Comment: I googled that book and read some bits and pieces of it. Just a warning for you if you aren't a native speaker: the English in the book is pretty eccentric, and there are lots of errors in it (it really needs a good edit). I found it kind of hard to understand in places. Maybe it's Indian English?

Comment: What's the novel? It'd be better if we had more details.

Comment: Related SE question: [What is actually being doubled when someone has to “double back”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/95092/50044)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Double back** — [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/double+back)

> to go back in the opposite direction (esp in the phrase **double back on one's tracks**)

So you are reluctantly replying to "I love you".